# Install MySQL on Nitrous.io Error

Tags: mysql, meteor, nitrousio

I'm having problems installing MySQL on my nitrous.io box. I run the `parts install MySQL` command but get the following error:

```
    Installing MySQL system tables...
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 4575 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 512 (requested 5000)
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 4575 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_cache: 400 (requested 2000)
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 4575 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 4575 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 4575 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 4575 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    2014-04-12 20:34:20 4575 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 12 MB
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 7f04ae363740 InnoDB: Error: Write to file ./ibdata1 failed at offset 0.
    InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 73728 were written.
    InnoDB: Operating system error number 2.
    InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
    InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
    InnoDB: Error number 2 means 'No such file or directory'.
    InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
    InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error in creating ./ibdata1: probably out of disk space
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [ERROR] Aborting

    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [Note] Binlog end
    2014-04-12 20:34:21 4575 [Note] /home/action/.parts/packages/mysql/5.6.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

    parts: ERROR: "scripts/mysql_install_db --basedir=/home/action/.parts/packages/mysql/5.6.13 --datadir=/home/action/.parts/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp --user=action --verbose" failed
    Aborting!
```

Also has anyone got any experience using MySQL with Meteor and does it have any seriously negative impacts performance wise. I found a pretty good article [here](http://www.fastcolabs.com/3007015/how-use-mysql-meteor,) but doesn't discuss performance and is a year old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem!

I didn't have enough space left on my nitrous box. MySQL wanted at least 450MB of space and I didn't have enough. Adding additional space and restarting my box resolved my issue/